# Can I save images from Facepixelizer as a PNG?

Tags: facepixelizer

Whenever I download an image which has been edited with [Facepixelizer](https://www.facepixelizer.com/), the end result is always saved as a compressed JPEG. This adds unnecessary compression to areas of the image I didn't want altered.

**Is there a way to prevent compression by saving in a different format, such as PNG?**

Comment: The default *save as* format seems to be only *jpg* which cannot be changed by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the solution was much simpler than I thought.

Just right click the image and click **Save image as...** to save as an uncompressed PNG.

[image]